# how to install ports in non-interactive way?

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to install ports as below. but, I'm getting jx prompt options to select. The flow should go with default options or anyway to give the input as yes through command line itself thats fair enough. In short, i should install ports non interactive way. kindly let me know the solution
`make ports`
I've tried `make ports BATCH=yes`. but didnt workout.

Comment: What makefile are you using?

Comment: sorry not understood

Comment: the command it is installing redis,and other third party packages..during the installing its prompting set NLS(native lang support) and others which makes me enter OK button for prompt

Comment: Please be more specific. What is "ports", what is your platform, what outcome you get (literally) and what do you expect.

Comment: im using freebsd OS. in freebsd ports means packages. im mentioning all my packages in a file and calling it from Makefile. so it is installing my ports(packages) but the problem is during the installation im getting jx prompts for inputs(need to select Native language support and other options to select) Im clicking OK button(it doesnt matter what options im selecting im justing clicking OK). so i want it in non interactively way. whatever the defaults options are there it should continue with those options only.